# Escaping from Equation Editor in VBA Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am opening Equation Editor in MS Word programmatically by using the code

```
Set objRange = Selection.Range
Set objRange = Selection.OMaths.Add(objRange)

Selection.TypeText Text:="a^2 + b^2 = c^2"
Selection.TypeText Text:="1/2"
Set objEq = objRange.OMaths(1)
objEq.Type = wdOMathInline
objEq.BuildUp
```

Now I want to exit Equation Editor so that I can type some regular text. I can't find a straightforward way. I have a workaround, which effectively means hitting enter and then going backspace once.

```
Selection.TypeParagraph
Selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

But isn't there a cleaner way?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the revision. I'm still not a regular user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it's actually very simple. Type

```
  Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1
```

after the equation is built up.